# Is it possible to use LSTM for time series forecasting for future months with test data having only NaN values?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, forecasting

my dataset is a univariate time series with one column as months, other column having demands for the corresponding months. My test dataset has NaN vals only for all the months. Can LSTM be used in this case and if so, how?
I tried using LSTM but only got NaN values. If you could help me out, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence but NNs do not understand strings, only numerical values. Hence, you should convert them.

Comment: I don't need the months as of now, so no need to convert them, my focus is the other column, which is the numeric demands, but since I have to forecast for the future months, I don't have any values, hence, NaN, like there is 12 months of numeric data and other 6 future months' demand needs to be forecasted.